# Deliver python external libraries with script

Tags: python

I want to use my script that uses pandas library on another linux machine where is no internet access or pip installed. 
Is there a way how to deliver the script with all dependencies?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).

It can create single executable file with included python or directory for distribution.

Comment: Can it generate something else than .exe ? Since i am gonna use it on linux without wine.

Comment: It can generate `directory for distribution`, just zip and transfer. I was under impression you are working from linux for linux. If package is not pure python I doubt that windows version would work on linux. If you choose pyinstaller use it on another linux environment eg. VM or WSL.

Comment: There are also docker containers for building exe/binary https://github.com/cdrx/docker-pyinstaller
Didn't test it, but it might be worth to look into.

Answer (score 0):

or set needed dependices in script manually by appending `sys.modules` and pack together all the needed files.